Why am I getting an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error message when I try to pass data to a popup?
I have code that looks like this:
public async Task CopyUsr(object sender)
{
    var dataView = sender as SfDataGrid;

    PswdWthGrp row = (PswdWthGrp)dataView!.SelectedRow;

    if (row != null)
    {
        await Clipboard.SetTextAsync(row.UsrName);
        popupService.ShowPopup<MsgViewModel>(onPresenting: vw => vw.PerformUpdts("User Name copied.", "Copied..."));
        await Task.Delay(1500);
        popupService.ClosePopup();
        return;
    } 
}

This is triggered when I select an option from a context menu from an sfDataGrid.
Now the popup XAML code is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ctm:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:ctm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
           xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:LockAndKeyMaui.ViewModels"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LockAndKeyMaui.MsgBox"
           CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="False"
           Color="Blue">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Success!"
            Margin="5,5,0,0" FontSize="20"
            FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="Arial"
            TextColor="White" x:Name="lblHdr"/>
        <Label 
            Text="Completed Successfully..."
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            FontSize="16" FontFamily="Arial"
            TextColor="Yellow" x:Name="lblMsg"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ctm:Popup>

And the view model for the popup is:
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace LockAndKeyMaui.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MsgViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string? msgtxt, hdrtxt;

        public string MsgTxt
        {
            get => msgtxt!;
            set
            {
                msgtxt = value;
                OnPropChg(nameof(MsgTxt));
            }
        }

        public string HdrTxt
        {
            get => hdrtxt!;
            set
            {
                hdrtxt = value;
                OnPropChg(nameof(HdrTxt));
            }
        }

        private readonly IPopupService popupService;

        public MsgViewModel(IPopupService popupService)
        {
            this.popupService = popupService;
        }

        /*    
    public void DisplayPopup()
    {
        this.popupService.ShowPopup<UpdatingPopupViewModel>(onPresenting: viewModel => viewModel.PerformUpdates(10));
    }
        */
        public void DisplayPopup(string ptxt, string phdr = "")
        {
            this.popupService.ShowPopup<MsgViewModel>(onPresenting: vwMod => vwMod.PerformUpdts(ptxt, phdr));
        }

        public void PerformUpdts(string txt, string hdr = "")
        {
            HdrTxt = hdr;
            MsgTxt = txt;
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropChg(string prName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prName));
        }
    }
}

So my question is why am I getting the error message:

'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

What is going wrong?
